# Подключения к прокси

Tags: php, proxy

Есть мой сервер на `PHP`. Есть прокси сервер `http`. Нужно как то подключиться к проски.

Как это сделать на `PHP`?

Answer (score 2):

Для `file_get_contents` подойдет

```
stream_context_set_default(['http'=>['proxy'=>'proxy-host:proxy-port']]);
```

Для `cURL`

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "8080");
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "[username]:[password]");
```